# How to update a variable that is Option[A] based on new values

Tags: scala

Sorry for what appears to be a Scala newbie question but lets say I have a variable "minVal" that is Option[Int] that is in a class. I need to update that variable if I get a new observation that is larger. Actually, I have many other variables -- e.g., maxVal, minDates, maxDates, minLength, maxLength, etc. Below is just a small snippet. So in addition to Option[Int], I also have Option[Date], Option[String] that have a similar update requirement.

I was wondering if there is a better way to calculate a min.

```
var minVal:Option[Int] = None
def registerObs(x: Option[Int]) = {
  if (x.isDefined) 
    minVal match {
      case None                   => minVal = x
      case Some(mv) if mv < x.get => minVal = x
      case _ => 
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let say that quite an "un-functional" (side-effect, mutability, ...)

Comment: Agreed --- sadly un-functional but I need to record different events. And a class instance per event type seems like a good approach.

Comment: There is *few* case where such approach can be recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe? 
`minVal = (minVal ++ x).reduceOption(_ min _)`

Also, you should not need different functions for different type. Something like this should be enough:

```
def minOpt[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A])(implicit o: Ordering[A]) =
   (x ++ y).reduceOption { o.min(_,_) }
```

And then:

```
minVal = minOpt(minVal, x)
minDate = minOpt(minDate, d)
minString = minOpt(minString, s)
```